# Datatables 1.9.4: data-order attribute is ignored

Tags: javascript, datatables

> Prologue: My table is rendered server-side and then, client-side, is enanched by Datatables, version 1.9.4. So, no ajax-related issues

I've a column with a money amount per cell. Actually, sorting it I obtain that

- 1
- 10
- 2
- 20

etc..

So i tried adding to every TD a `data-sort` attribute to use the numeric value instead of formatted one.

But Sorting is absolutely ignoring it.

Must I enable in some way or install a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `columnDefs`, field type `num` [as the documentation says](https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/)

```
$('#TableId').dataTable({
  ...
  "columnDefs": [
    { "type": "num", targets: 3 } // Change targets to your column number, it starts in 0
  ]
  ...
});
```